# unable to launch application into the emulator

Tags: android

```
                   Android Launch!

[2011-05-23 10:28:49 - Trivia Quiz] adb is running normally.
[2011-05-23 10:28:49 - Trivia Quiz] No Launcher activity found!
[2011-05-23 10:28:49 - Trivia Quiz] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2011-05-23 10:28:49 - Trivia Quiz] Performing sync
[2011-05-23 10:28:49 - Trivia Quiz] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'TQ' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2011-05-23 10:28:52 - Trivia Quiz] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-05-23 10:28:52 - Trivia Quiz] \Trivia Quiz\bin\Trivia Quiz.apk installed on device
[2011-05-23 10:28:52 - Trivia Quiz] Done!
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no launcher Activity in your application. Add one to the manifest file. Something like this (add this into `<application>` tag):

```
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Upvoted - You beat me to it! Everyone else was fooled by the `Application already deployed` bit.

Answer (score 1):

Deployment <> (is different from) launch.

What this "trace" says is that you're trying to install an application that already exists.

Then you just need to open it as you would normally do.

But I presume you want to install a *newer* version of the application.

I don't remember (not at home to test it in fact) the command but you can use "adb uninstall application-name.apk" or something like that before trying to deploy your application. And then it would solve the problem.

Read the manual, an "overwrite" parameter may exist for the install "goal".

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling it on the emulator. Menu --> Settings --> Applications --> Trivia Quiz --> Uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall your Application , and Install it again

in your Emulator , go to : Settings ==> Applications ==> Manage Applications == > and uninstall your Application